# Why can't I add my custom model binder in my global.asax folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, global-asax, custom-model-binder

I see examples all over the net of people setting up their custom model binders like this:

```
// global.asax
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(YourModel), new YourBinder());
}
```

But when I try that, it doesn't compile (`.Binders` isn't found). What gives?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turns out this was just a naming conflict because I had put my custom model binder *in a folder/namespace* called "ModelBinders". You can fix this one of two ways:

1. Rename the namespace/folder to something else, e.g. `CustomModelBinders`
2. Use a fully qualified reference to the `ModelBinders` like this:

   `System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinders.Binders.Add( /* ... */ );`

Comment: Thanks Michael It works. Don't know the reason why but it's running.